# How to copy file from local into rootless podman container

Tags: docker, containers, podman

I'm trying to add nexu repo 3 on podman rootless container. I was successful in adding those on podman with mount volumn (nfs). Now my concern  is I want to copy of file from local into this rootless container,  I tried to do it with docker command like podman cp /some/dir/file containerid:path. But this gives me permission denied error. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I wrote a [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#33-container-creates-a-file-that-is-not-owned-by-the-users-regular-uid) and a [tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem)  in the Podman troubleshooting document. They explain how to use __--uidmap__ and __--gidmap__. Maybe they could be useful?